# Query : How to use Spring-DM powered OSGi bundle exposed as a webservice

Tags: spring, web, service, osgi, spring-dm

I've been working on a project to create OSGi bundles and expose them as a service. I've read enough on OSGi service and I must say I've fair idea on it.
I've just come across the Spring-DM framework and having a quick look at its reference manual, I must say I'm very excited to use it as it provides fairly simple "declarative" way to expose bundle as a service.

However, I've not been able to figure out how can I expose my bundle as a "web-service" using Spring-DM.

I'd a look at the below link which shows how Apache-CXF can be used along with Spring-DM to expose bundle as a webservice:

http://cxf.apache.org/dosgi-spring-dm-demo-page.html

However, I could not understand the part where they have explained "endpoint-descriptions" tag part.

Can someone pls suggest/guide me on using Spring-DM to expose my bundle as a "web-service" ?

Many thanks in advance.

Best Regards
LB

Answer (score 1):

Spring dm is kind of deprecated and is not maintained anymore. I propose to rather look into blueprint which is similar in syntax.
You can use cxf dosgi or plain cxf. In DOSGi you simply publish an OSGi service with special properties. It is then exposed as a webservice. In plain cxf you define an endpoint in blueprint. The plain cxf way allows more control over the service but binds you directly to the cxf framework.

I have tutorials for both aproaches:

- Plain CXf: http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/EoBk
- DOSGi: http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/D4C

Comment: Thanks Christian. Had a look at both articles and they sound interesting in exposing OSGi service as a web service. However, I would still like to try my hands-on with spring-dm first. I've been searching all over the internet but still not able to find one straight forward tutorial that explains use of Spring-DM + Maven + OSGi + JAX-WS. In short, I need an article that explains exposing my POJO as a webservice and bundle it as an OSGi bundle via Maven. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.